# Read *.csv as list from multiple folders

Tags: r, csv

I have thousands of *csv files in multiple folders `../t1/*.csv`,`../t2/*.csv`,`../t3/*.csv`...etc.

I can upload the files from multiple folders as following:

```
filenames <- list.files(c("C:/Example/t1","C:/Example/t2"), pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
list.df <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)
```

However I have to type in all the directories `C:/Example/t1`, `C:/Example/t2` etc. How to read all data (as list of data.frames) with one main directory somethign like: `C:/Example/*`?

Comment: what's "uploading" got to do with it? Do you know what that means?

Comment: Try reading the help for `list.files` and especially the `recursive` parameter.

Comment: ok, would `read` suit better? No it doesn't work with only `"C:/Example/`, I have tried already.

Comment: Would something like that work? `n <- 4;
filenames <- list.files(paste0(rep("C:/Example/t", n), seq_len(n)), pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)` Where your define `n` as the number of you folders

Comment: @David. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `list.files` with `recursive=TRUE` will search all folders under the first argument for matching files:

```
> list.files("./",recursive=TRUE)
[1] "a/a1.csv"    "a/a2.csv"    "a/notme.txt" "b/b1.csv"    "d/e/e1.csv"
```

That's all the files under my current directory, if I only want CSVs:

```
> list.files("./",recursive=TRUE,pattern="*.csv")
[1] "a/a1.csv"   "a/a2.csv"   "b/b1.csv"   "d/e/e1.csv"
```

Notice how it looks in the second-level `d/e/` folder?

If you only want to go to a single, specific depth, try `Sys.glob` - these patterns match folders and files and these examples work from the current directory:

Only first level:

```
> Sys.glob("*/*.csv")
[1] "a/a1.csv" "a/a2.csv" "b/b1.csv"
```

Only second level:

```
> Sys.glob("*/*/*.csv")
[1] "d/e/e1.csv"
```

Comment: I've found the `dir` function helpful in the past.  For example `dir(pattern = 't[0-9]')`.  Is `list.files` preferred over `dir`?  I don't see much usage of `dir` anywhere.